# How to implement sms-validation of registration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra

Site built on Sinatra, and got next code in actions:

```
post '/registration/sms/:number' do
  code = Random.rand(1111..9999).to_s
  phone = params[:phone].to_s
  HTTParty.get('http://sms.ru/sms/send?api_id=' + api_id +'&to=' + phone + '&text=' + code)
  # check code
end
```

With this view:

```
%form{:method => "post"}
  %div.form-group
    %label Phone number
    %input#phone.form-control{:name => "phone", :placeholder => "7 950 123 45 67"}
  %button#sendsms.btn.btn-default{"data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#myModal"} Send
```

And this JS:

```
$("#sendsms").click(function(){
  var phone = $("#phone").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/registration/sms",
    data: {"phone": phone},
    type: "post"
  })
})
```

I thought this JS should send **post** request to action, which creates new request to *sms.ru* wich sends sms. But it doesn't works, and I can't figure out why.

Thank you in advance for any help, especially for implementation without JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sinatra code expects `/registration/sms/:number`, but your ajax sends to `/registration/sms` with `phone: XXXXX` in the post data.

Change your server code to:

```
post '/registration/sms' do
  code = Random.rand(1111..9999).to_s
  phone = params[:phone].to_s
  HTTParty.get('http://sms.ru/sms/send?api_id=' + api_id +'&to=' + phone + '&text=' + code)
  # check code
end
```